# How to include JavaScript in the markdown used by Github for issues?

Tags: javascript, github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Our team has found the Issues feature of GitHub to be a great way to develop and share our internal ML research. We currently paste matplotlib-generated plots in the issue comments, but they are static images, and they quickly become out-of-date as models train over several days.

We would like to add a "refresh" link or button in the comment to enable the user to refresh the plot image from our team server.  I tried doing this with the markdown shown below, but it appears that the JavaScript is being ignored. Is there any way this can be done?

```
button test:
<a  href="#" onclick="img.src='https://teamserver/plotcmd'; event.preventDefault()">Refresh</a>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to *why* you believe GitHub would allow this sort of behavior? This would represent a massive security hole if arbitrary JavaScript could be executed in this context.

Comment: Hi esqew.  The goal is to enable the user to view the latest plot (or more generally data) related to an issue.  Javascript was the just first thing I thought of. If there were a way to bind data from web APIs to the text and images in Github's markdown, that would be ideal.   I'm open to any other ways of accomplishing this.  Thanks.